# Как сделать постраничный вывод по разделам в битрикс?

Tags: битрикс

В Битрикс есть компонент catalog.section, он выводит элементы раздела. 
Настроил в компоненте фильтр, что бы показывал данные с условием если "свойство инфоблока ХХХ = YYY".
Далее сгруппировал это все.
т.е. идет показ

Свойство YYY 1

- Элемент 1
- Элемент 2
- ...

Свойство YYY 2

- Элемент 1
- Элемент 2
- ...

Перенес в каждый блок постраничную навигацию. т.е. выходит

- Свойство YYY 1
- Элемент 1
- Элемент 2
- ...
- 1.2.3

  Свойство YYY 2
- Элемент 1
- Элемент 2
- ...
- 1.2.3

при нажатии на следующую страницу, мы переходим на следующую, но по всем свойствам YYY1 и YYY2.
Как ограничить что бы менялись страницы только в одном блоке?

Comment: У компонента news.list есть параметр "PAGER_BASE_LINK_ENABLE" - включает дополнительные опции постраничной навигации. После его включения можно использовать параметр "PAGER_PARAMS_NAME" - имя переменной для навигации. Можно задать для двух компонентов разные имена переменных и они будут переключаться независимо. https://dev.1c-bitrix.ru/user_help/components/content/articles_and_news/news_list.php#page_navigation_settings

Попробуйте эти же параметры добавить к catalog.section.

Comment: думаю что нужно просто как то ограничить выборку, но как не знаю. спасибо, сейчас попробую

Comment: Да, вот тут https://filter.kombox.ru/docs/course/?COURSE_ID=1&LESSON_ID=25&LESSON_PATH=1.12.25 явно указанно, что такие параметры есть у catalog.section. По сути, пагинация там работает на одном механизме с news.list. 


Просто в документации https://dev.1c-bitrix.ru/user_help/components/content/catalog/catalog_section.php куце описано.

Comment: При работе с Битриксом не стоит углубляться в такие низкоуровневые вещи, как ручное ограничение выборки. Все более-менее распространённые задачи уже продуманы за вас и реализуются вполне стандартными методами. Гуглите тщательнее - рецептов много. Низкоуровневые доработки плохо поддерживаются и зачастую могут сломать функционал, который вы не видите.